# Can't get rid of unwanted file change

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-stash, core.autocrlf

First, my develop is clear, `git status` is clear.

When I do `pull origin develop` followed by `git status`, it's shown below

```
 On branch develop
 Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

   modified:   app/services/thrift/idls/woss/open-api/deviceInfo_service.thrift

 no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I want to checkout this file, so I use commands like these

```
  git add .
  git checkout -- .
  git stash save --keep-index
  git checkout-index -a -f
  git config --global core.autocrlf false/true/input
  git config --global core.filemode false
```

But none of them works.

`git diff` shown below,

```
diff --git a/app/services/thrift/idls/woss/open-api/deviceInfo_service.thrift b/app/services/thrift/idls/woss/open-api/deviceInfo
index 7040bf3..062bec8 100644
--- a/app/services/thrift/idls/woss/open-api/deviceInfo_service.thrift
+++ b/app/services/thrift/idls/woss/open-api/deviceInfo_service.thrift
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
-namespace rb thrifts.result
+namespace rb ThriftService

 struct QueryDeviceInfo{
@@ -25,7 +25,7 @@ struct DeviceInfo{

 struct Result{
-    1:i32 stat_code,
+    1:i32 statCode,

    2:string errMsg;
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: "I want to checkout this file" What do you mean? A `git checkout -- .` would reset the index to HEAD, losing all current modification.

Comment: I want to discard the changes. To be exact, this modification is automatically generated, I do not know why and when this stuff is generated, and I can`t discard the changes, `git checkout -- .` can`t work.